# How can you get the same button to display an image in a sequence

Tags: arrays, swift, image

I'm starting out with a really simple app.
Whenever you press the main button I want the image to change in an order.

In this example it's an apple. So each time you press your button it should change to the next image (which has a bite taken out of it). Im using an array but so far all I can do is assign the image to change randomly each tim its pressed rather than: Display image 1, then image 2 then image 3 etc.

My code below:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

  var  appleArray = [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "apple1"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "apple2"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "apple3")]
    
    @IBOutlet weak var appleView: UIImageView!

    @IBAction func buttonView(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an instance var

```
var current = 0
```

Then every press do

```
appleView.image = appleArray[current]
current += 1
if current >= appleArray.count { // when you reach last image loop from the beginning 
  current = 0
}
```

Comment: One question i have is now the first image in the array does not appear when I run the app, and on the first button click it starts from image 2. Im guessing its because we are starting current at 1? is there any way to mitigate that?